# Unable to trace require_once error in PHP

Tags: php, file, require, php-7.1

i have a file structure like this in my PHP 7.1

```
Model/Abstract.php
Model/NTLStm.php
Model/SoapCl.php
Controller.php
```

i Called Model/Abstract.php in Controller like this:

```
use Model/Abstract as modelAbstract;

$abstract = new modelAbstract();
```

i tried to include the `Model/NTLStm.php` & `Model/SoapCl.php` in `Model/Abstract.php` like this:

```
defined('DS') OR define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . DS . 'SoapCl.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . DS . 'NTLStm.php';
echo 'success';
```

but it seems it always terminate the process in `require_once` , i already tried to put try catch like this:

```
try{
  defined('DS') OR define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

  require_once dirname(__FILE__) . DS . 'SoapCl.php';
  require_once dirname(__FILE__) . DS . 'NTLStm.php';
} catch(\Exception $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

but it won't print anything

Answer (score 0):

Try using parentheses with require_once...  like this:

```
require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . DS . 'SoapCl.php');
require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . DS . 'NTLStm.php');
```

Comment: it's working, but i still need to use the `dirname(__FILE__) . DS `

Comment: That's good news that it works...  So dirname just gets you the absolute path...